# global value not changing

Tags: python, global-variables, global

Why does this global variable not change?
And how can I make it so that I can use global functions and variables that can change?

**my_lib.py**

```
frame_count = 1

def init():
    global frame_count
    frame_count += 5
    print frame_count # prints 6
```

**b.py**

```
from my_lib import *

if __name__ == "__main__":
    init()
    print frame_count # prints 1 instead of 6!
```

edit:

My post is different then the marked duplicate, it's 10 times more simple to read! And the duplicate explains the problem, but not how to work around it.

Comment: Don't use `from my_lib import *`; you now created a new reference, `frame_count = sys.modules['my_lib'].frame_count` that can't follow changes to `sys.modules['my_lib'].frame_count`.

Comment: What should I use instead? The page you marked as a duplicate explains the problem. But it does now explain how to solve it.

Comment: @clankill3r Do `import my_lib` and then always use the full names `my_lib.frame_count` and `my_lib.init`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `my_lib.frame_count` has changed but not `frame_count` imported from my_lib.

Comment: With that I get `my_lib` is not defined. If I change the import to `import my_lib` then `init` is not defined. I'm running in circles.

Comment: @clankill3r As @VPfB saying, you could use `my_lib.init` with `import my_lib`.

Comment: But I want things global. I don't want to use a module prefix all the time. Am I looking for something that is not possible?

Comment: @clankill3r No, it's possible. But first you should understand clearly what happen. The critical reason you get 1 when `print frame_count` is that the type of `frame_count` is `int` and `int` is a value type but not a reference type. If you change `frame_count = 1` into `frame_count = [1]` and try to set or get the value by `frame_count[0]`, then you can call `print frame_count[0]` in `b.py` to print expected value. Because now `frame_count` is a reference of `sys.modules['my_lib'].frame_count` but not a copy. So if you real want to share global variables, you can only share reference variable